# Differents way to define a function in sagemath

Tags: python, sage

I would like to know why these two "programs" produce different output

```
    f(x)=x^2
    f(90).mod(7)
```

and

```
    def f(x):
        return(x^2)
    f(90).mod(7)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Great question!  Let's take a deeper look at the functions in question.

```
f(x)=x^2
def g(x):
    return(x^2)

print type(g(90))
print type(f(90))
```

This yields

```
<type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>
<type 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression'>
```

So what you are seeing is the difference between a *symbolic* function defined with the `f(x)` notation and a *Python* function using the `def` keyword.  In Sage, the former has access to a lot of stuff (e.g. calculus) that plain old Sage integers won't have.

What I would recommend in this case, just for what you need, is

```
sage: a = f(90)
sage: ZZ(a).mod(7)
1
```

or actually the possibly more robust

```
sage: mod(a,7)
1
```

---

Longer explanation.

For symbolic stuff, `mod` isn't what you think.  In fact, I'm not sure it will do anything (see the documentation for `mod` to see how to use it for polynomial modular work over ideals, though).  Here's the code (accessible with `x.mod??`, documentation accessible with `x.mod?`):

```
    from sage.rings.ideal import is_Ideal
    if not is_Ideal(I) or not I.ring() is self._parent:
        I = self._parent.ideal(I)
        #raise TypeError, "I = %s must be an ideal in %s"%(I, self.parent())
    return I.reduce(self)
```

And it turns out that for generic rings (like the symbolic 'ring'), nothing happens in that last step:

```
return f
```

This is why we need to, one way or another, ask it to be an integer again.  See [Trac 27401](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/27401).